# location.href not redirecting to https:// urls

Tags: php, javascript

Have been using the following on a form's Thankyou page to redirect back to the form in 5 seconds and neatly pre-fill the name fields with values:

```
<script> setTimeout(function() {location.href = '<?php echo $var3['returnurl']  ?>?fullName[first]=<?php echo $var1['first'] ?>&fullName[last]=<?php echo $var2['last']  ?>'}, 5000); </script>
```

Works great until the returnurl field is a https:// url. 
Then it stays on the thankyou page in a loop trying to do the redirect.
There are no iframes involved .... have tried top.location.href ... no good ... even tried location.replace

Can anyone see any limitations with the code that may be impacting the redirect to an https:// url.

Code in the php file  ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no"> 
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
  <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="width">

    <title>Thankyou</title>

    <style type="text/css">

body 
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background: #fff;
font-family: Arial;
}

#message
{
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
width: 320px;
margin-left: -160px;
}

</style>

<?php
$answers = $_POST;
$var1 = array("first" => $answers[fullname][0]);
$var2 = array("last" => $answers[fullname][1]);
$var3 = array("returnurl" => $answers[returnurl]);
 ?> 

</head>

<body>

<script>
  setTimeout(function() {location.href = '<?php echo $var3['returnurl']  ?>?fullName[first]=<?php echo $var1['first'] ?>&fullName[last]=<?php echo $var2['last']  ?>'}, 5000); // this duration is in millisecs
</script>

<div id="message">

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div style="text-align: center;"><h1>Thank You!</h1></div>
<div style="text-align: center;">Your submission has been received.</div>
<div style="text-align: center;">We're most grateful</div>
<div style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="text-align: center;"><img src="http://www.mazeguy.net/bigsmilies/thumbsup.gif"></img></div>
<div style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="text-align: center;">You will return in 5 seconds</div><br />

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the result of a submission ... the Thankyou Page source shows ... yeah the secure page url is not being passed through ....

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {location.href = '?fullName[first]=&fullName[last]='}, 5000); //     this duration is in millisecs
</script>
```

Comment: Please show us the rendered HTML.

Comment: is the script actually embedded on the page like that or is that just for our readability?  I mean is it being included like <script src="...." on your page?

Comment: @Rooster It's most-likely inline in his .php file.

Comment: @Mark what is the value of $var3['returnurl'] ?

Comment: @Jackson yeah, I agree.  But theres not a lot of info there, so I thought it worth throwing out there that trying to call a http script from https or vice versa could run him into some problems.  And I post my questions as simple as possible usually, so thought maybe he did too.

Comment: look at the `view-source:` of the page and see what code is generated

Comment: Hi, 
the thankyou page is a php file ...
the script is embedded on the page in the php file
The value of $var3['returnurl'] is actually just pulling from a field .. so I set the url as the forms own url ...
Sorry .. a little to the site and its nuances...
How can I help ..please advise

Comment: Excuse my rank amateur handling of this affair. I promise to improve. I have added the code in the php file above. Thanks mark

Comment: As it has been noted here, we need to know how the script tag is being rendered in the browser, open the page and use `view page source` or Ctrl+U in Chrome

Comment: Have added the result of a submission i.e. the source shows the script tag to not have pulled through the https:// url

Comment: it's not showing any of your php values, try adding `var_dump($_POST)` to see how the post values are being submitted

Comment: Why to use JavaScript? Wouldn't it be better to use the `REFRESH` parameter via `header()` function?

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered submitting the form via Ajax? The user would never leave the form submission page. You could simply display a modal with the confirmation message. That seems simpler than redirecting the user. It may be a nicer user experience as well.

Let's assume your form has a submit button with a class of 'submit'. You could so something like this in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var target = event.currenTarget;
        var form = $(target).closest('form');
        var action = $(form).attr('action');
        $.post(action, form.serialize())
            .done(function() {
                alert('Thanks for your submission!');
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert('Oops! Something went wrong... PLease try again.');
            });
    });   
});
```

Check out Bootstrap. They have some nifty looking modals you can use.